# numpy - incrementally rebuild an ndarray by filtering unneded members

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Consider that I have an ndarray:

```
all_data.shape
(220000, 28, 28)

type(all_data)
numpy.ndarray
```

I want to go over each member of this array and filter out those which I don't want. As result I want to get new ndarray of exactly same shape.

Something like:

```
#save first image and its label in separate array
#we will store unique values
sanitized_data = all_data[0]
sanitized_labels = all_labels[0]
#lets illimnate dupes
#store of existing hashes
hashes = set()
#go over each image
for i in range(0,len(all_labels)):
    #check if its hash is in list hashes
    if not md5(all_data[i]).hexdigest() in hashes:
        #record its hash and copy to new dataset
        sanitized_data = np.stack((sanitized_data, all_data[i]))
        sanitized_labels = np.stack((sanitized_labels, all_labels[i]))      
        hashes.add(md5(all_data[i]).hexdigest())
```

But I get:

```
ValueError: all input arrays must have the same shape
```

I am not sure how to properly do this. I want to incrementally add new array along first axis once I find the array I like. Not sure how to properly do this with numpy? I googled dstack action for that, but seems like it stacks stuff along wrong axis.

Comment: What do you mean by `filter out`?  Set to 0, or remove.  If you remove elements you can't retain the same shape.

Comment: May I suggest pulling up numpy in a Python session, make some small arrays with various shapes, and practice concatentating them along different axes.  `np.concatenate` is the basic action.  `hstack`, `dstack` etc just adjust dimensions and concatatenate on some axis.  Don't stumble around in the dark.  Practice with something small and observable.

Comment: It is better to accumulate component arrays in a list, and apply `concatenate` once to the whole list.  Also get in the habit checking dimensions as you go along.

Comment: @hpaulj last suggestion worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied from comments:

It is better to accumulate component arrays in a list, and apply `concatenate` once to the whole list.  Also get in the habit checking dimensions as you go along.

@hpaulj last suggestion worked, thanks!